# Mean value of a function over $R$

Tags: calculus, functions

Over an interval $[a, b] $ we can define the mean value of a function $f$ as
$$\overline{f} = \frac{\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) dx} {b-a}. $$
Is there a formula for the mean value of a function over $R$?

Comment: Take the limit. ($b \to +\infty, a \to -\infty$)

Comment: It is useful sometimes to consider the integral from -R to +R and then put the limit as $R\to\infty$. Note that this doesn't always exist, not even for continuous functions, and moreover if you change one of the extremes and compute the limit in an asymmetric way, this might change.

Comment: For example for the function $e^{-a|t|} $ the outcome with this formula is zero. It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

One way of extending it would be to take the limit symmetrically:
$$\lim_{c \to +\infty}\frac{1}{2c}\int_{-c}^c f(x)\,\mbox{d}x$$
Of course, functions with a finite integral on $\mathbb{R}$ will then have a mean of $0$. Constant functions have a mean equal to their function value.

> For example for the function $e^{-a|t|}$ the outcome with this formula is zero. It doesn't make any sense.

The mean of $e^{-|kt|}$ on $[a,b]$ becomes arbitrarily small if you take $b-a$ sufficiently large. Why would any finite but strictly positive number make (more) sense to you, in this case?

Comment: If the result was 1 that would be more logical. Differently put is there a formula that can give symmetrical functions the average value of f(0)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _"the average value of f(0)"_; f(0) is just a number...?

Comment: The average value of function f= f(0).

Comment: I see you edited your comment and changed 0 to 1 as what you would find 'more logical'. But why 1? On a sufficiently large interval, the mean would become _a lot_ smaller than 1... So why would it be logical to be 1 on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I edited because I made a mistake I meant 1. I know that the answer should be 1, the professor told so. It is more logical imo because it's a value that the function takes (f(0)) while 0 is not even a value of the  function. Function is positive on R. Anyway I don't really care what is more logical but how to force the function to have this value as average :)

Comment: You lost me (I don't see how this is going to make sense); but if that's what you're looking for: then _define_ its mean as f(0) and you're done! :-). It loses its interpretation as some sort of 'mean' though, in my opinion.

Comment: Fair enough. I mark it answered as my initial question was answered

Comment: Perhaps someone else can still help you further. I don't see how or why your professor would say that this function _should have_ a mean of 1 (on $\mathbb{R}$) since its mean on _any interval_ is smaller than 1 and the mean only decreases if you enlarge the interval.